# What can specify in executable file name in vc++ Project

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2003

I am beginner in VC++. I create a simple VC++ ATL Project.when i will debug the project then it ask for Executable file Name. which file is enterd in the Executable file name.?

Answer (score 0):

You probably created a DLL project. Such DLL can be used by some executable. So, you should provide there a name of the executable that will load and use your DLL. Another option is to create another test project (executable) that will load and use your DLL. That would be just for testing purposes.

Comment: add DLL then gives an error enable to start debugging.Enable to start Program "path of DLL".

Comment: Try modifying working directory under Debugging tab. Set it to path of your DLL.

Comment: If you want help, you need to provide much more details.

Comment: I do that..File->New->Project After that select Visual c++ then select ATL Project. Then give the name then OK.After that i try to debugg then that ask for Executable file Name.

Comment: No, you didn't. ATL project can create 3 types of application: dll, exe and service (also exe). Based on your question, you selected the default one, the DLL. But, since we are still at the beginning, the question for you would be: "do you know what DLL is?"

Comment: First ATL Project after that 3 types of application: dll, exe and service (also exe). i select DLL

Comment: If you know what DLL is, how come you cannot use it with some test exe created just for that purpose?

Comment: i delete which one i created then tell me how to create and debug the project step by step.